# how to attach scrollbar to a dialog

Tags: c++, image

I have to find the correct way to attach a scrollbar to a set of images that are created dynamically by the application. 
In my code I create the scrollbar but it is not working properly. The main window does not scroll to view all the images.

```
int currentLength = iImage * (WIDTH + SPACER); 
picName.Format(_T("Image %d"),iImage);
CPoint topLeft(currentLength,0);
CPoint bottomRigth(currentLength + (WIDTH), HEIGHT);

CRect miniCRect(topLeft, bottomRigth);
Miniature[iImage] = new CStatic();
Miniature[iImage]->Create(picName, WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|SS_BITMAP, miniCRect, this);   

if((bottomRigth.x > 500) && (currentLength <= 500))
{
    //creo la scrool bar
    CPoint ptnrigin(0,210);
    CPoint endptn(bottomRigth.x,230);
    CRect workingArea(ptnrigin,endptn);
    cs.Create(WS_VISIBLE,workingArea,this,0);
    cs.EnableScrollBar(ESB_ENABLE_BOTH);
    SCROLLINFO info;
    info.cbSize = sizeof(SCROLLINFO);     
    info.fMask = SIF_ALL;     
    info.nMin = 1;     
    info.nMax = 10; 
    info.nPage = 2;     
    info.nPos = 5;    
    info.nTrackPos = 5; 
    cs.SetScrollInfo(&info);
}

HDC hDCScreen_mini = ::CreateDC(_T("DISPLAY"), NULL, NULL, NULL);
HDC hDCMem_mini = ::CreateCompatibleDC(hDCScreen_mini);
// create a compatible bitmap and select it in the memory DC
HBITMAP hBitmap_mini = ::CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDCScreen_mini, miniCRect.Width(), miniCRect.Height());
HBITMAP hBmpOld_mini = (HBITMAP)::SelectObject(hDCMem_mini, hBitmap_mini);

BitBlt(hDCMem_mini, 0, 0, desktopRect.Width(), desktopRect.Height(), hDCScreen_mini, desktopRect.left, desktopRect.top, dwRop);

Miniature[iImage]->SetBitmap(hBitmap_mini);
Invalidate();

// restore the memory DC and perform cleanup
SelectObject(hDCMem_mini, hBmpOld_mini);
DeleteDC(hDCMem_mini);
DeleteDC(hDCScreen_mini);
//end capture
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A scrollbar does not scroll your window or its contents. It only provides input from the user to code that you must write to reposition the images. Such code typically uses ScrollWindow to move the visible portion, followed by adding the newly-visible portion in WM_PAINT.

A different approach (that does do the scrolling for you) would be to put the images in an owner-drawn list box.

Comment: there is no way to notify the new size of parent dialog to allow the scrolling?

Comment: Scrolling does not cause "the new size of parent dialog". It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: I search something like Panel on c#. In a Panel is easy to scrooll elements.

Comment: It is easy to scroll elements with CScrollView and CFormView. But these are only available in the MFC library. It looks like you are programming at the Win32 API level, which requires more work.